# where to add Access-Control-Allow-Headers to the response in ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, api

**My Code:**

```
  $.ajax({
            origin: "*",
            url: 'http://SP/api/test',
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            crossDomain: true,
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("API_KEY", "XX");
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "XX";
            },
            success: function (data) {          
                });
            },
            error: function (y) {

            }
        });
```

**Request Headers:**

```
GET http://SP/api/testcallback=jQuery22406877213234276709_1489930192633&_=1489930192634 HTTP/1.1Host:http://SP/
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*

Referer: http://SP/api/test
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

I believe that I should add **Access-Control-Allow-Headers** but I didn't know where to add.

Comment: At least related: [*Add CORS header to an http request using Ajax*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37527962/add-cors-header-to-an-http-request-using-ajax)

Answer (score 1):

In your client-side code? Nowhere. That's a **response** header the server would send back, **if** it wants to allow your origin to make ajax calls to it with those headers.

More in [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/).

Comment: Api working correctly with authorization and return right data but gives error 403 Forbidden when I called it from Jquery ajax.

Comment: @azzaali: Right. Because cross-origin requests are not allowed by default; the server has to allow them.

Comment: how the server allow them, i'm working with api on asp.net mvc . @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @azzaali: By responding to the request with appropriate headers. See the spec and the linked question's answers.