# Prometheus Pushgateway from Browser JS/AJAX

Tags: javascript, client, prometheus, prometheus-pushgateway

I am searching for an example on how to push metric to the pushgateway via ajax.

```
echo 'some_metric 42' | curl --user user:pass --data-binary @- https://example.com/metrics/job/author_monitoring/jobname/count_open
```

with curl it works perfect!

I don't know how to translate this in js/jquery.
Maybe someone has an example

Here is what I got so far.

```
(function ($, $document) {
  "use strict";

  function textToBin(text) {
    return (
      Array
      .from(text)
      .reduce((acc, char) => acc.concat(char.charCodeAt().toString(2)), [])
      .map(bin => '0'.repeat(8 - bin.length) + bin)
      .join(' ')
    );
  }

  var username = "user";
  var password = "pass";
  var metric = 'some_metric 42';
  var binaryData = textToBin(metric);

  $.ajax({
    url: "https://example.com/metrics/job/author_monitoring/jobname/count_open",
    data: binaryData,
    type: 'POST',
    crossDomain: true,
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));
    },
    success: function () {
      console.log("Success");
    },
    error: function () {
      console.log('Failed!');
    }
  });

})($, $(document));
```

here is the error:

```
text format parsing error in line 1: invalid metric name
```

Comment: Well, for one thing, [CORS doesn't work like that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37527962/add-cors-header-to-an-http-request-using-ajax). But it's not clear from your question whether you're having a CORS issue or something else. In any case, remove the header.

Comment: its not an cors error I guess, the pushgateway returns 400. `text format parsing error in line 1: invalid metric name`

Answer (score 0):

okay I got it.

There is an easy solution, import is the `\n` at the end of the string.

```
(function ($, $document) {
  "use strict";
  var username = "user";
  var password = "pass";
  var metric = 'some_metric 42\n';

  $.ajax({
    url: "https://example.com/metrics/job/author_monitoring/jobname/count_open",
    data: metric,
    type: 'POST',
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
    },
    success: function () {
      console.log("Success");
    },
    error: function () {
      console.log('Failed!');
    }
  });
})($, $(document));
```