# How to correctly assign Headers to fetch request in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm quite new to more advanced APIs, and I'm trying to send a GET request to an external API using fetch, with the appropriate Headers as detailed by the API owner.

However, I'm still receiving a 403 Forbidden error, and it seems that the headers are not actually being sent with the request as the Chrome DevTools shows:

> "Provisional headers are being shown".

I'm using a CORS proxy: https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/, which has worked with other simpler API requests.

```
const proxy = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';
const api = `${proxy}https://api-example.com`; // Obfuscated


// Generate the data
fetch(api, data = {}, {
    credentials: "include",
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: "Bearer eLrw3eXlljyFRjaul5UoYZLNgpUeapbXSFKmLc5SVaBgv8azUtoKn7B062PjbYoS",
      "User-Agent": "any-name"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
})
    .then(response => {
        return response.text();
    })
```

The API request works in Postman and using curl, but with my application I receive a 403 Forbidden response. As also mentioned, only provisional headers are shown in the request headers; none of the headers I had set.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: step 1 - do not put CORS response headers in a request to try and self-authorize CORS - that's not how CORS works - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37527962/add-cors-header-to-an-http-request-using-ajax

Comment: Gotcha - took those headers out, thanks. Step 2..? :D

Comment: Inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network and you should see that the headers are there. It may be that the proxy service isn't handling them properly, could be a cookie issue also. The credentials you include will not be for the api since that's not where request is being made. Create your own proxy on server you control

Comment: not sure - forbidden means forbidden - does `cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com` pass on all authentication headers etc? the problem with using that damned cors-anywhere proxy is, you don't know what it does, so is the error coming from it, or the final destination?

Comment: The other problem with cors-anywhere is that when I try to test this it is spitting out *Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 429 (Too Many Requests)*

Comment: from an API point of view, `cors-anywhere` and the like, is easy enough to block - I do it all the time - because CORS is there for a reason - to stop rogue sites from "borrowing" other peoples resources - if a site does not want you to use its API directly from a browser, respect that decision, and use their API the way they want you to ... sites like `cors-anywhere` should be shut down ... end rant

Comment: Thats interesting @JaromandaX. What do you suggest to get around the CORS issue when trying to request from localhost? Using a proxy was the only workaround I was aware of, but happy to try other things

Comment: I didn't say don't use a proxy ... *charlietfl* mentioned the correct way to do it *Create your own proxy on server you control*

Answer (score 7):

It looks as though you are passing an empty object as the options. The fetch() function only takes two parameters, the `resource` (uri) and an object of `options` (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch). You have an empty object `data = {}` as the second parameter and your options specified as an unused, third parameter. I believe what you want is to remove the `data` parameter, especially since you don't need to send a `body` in a GET request.

```
fetch(api, {
    credentials: "include",
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: "Bearer eLrw3eXlljyFRjaul5UoYZLNgpUeapbXSFKmLc5SVaBgv8azUtoKn7B062PjbYoS",
      "User-Agent": "any-name"
    }
})
.then(response => {
    return response.text();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The api works in Postman and curl and if you are sure you are sending all request and headers same way then it probably is CORS issue. You have not provided enough information to truly understand if that is the case.

However I am trying to explain what I understand how CORS work for browsers. Browsers before making a request (e.g GET, POST, DELETE etc) makes an OPTIONS request. If the server that handles the request sees that the request is allowed for that host (using the origin and a few other factors), the server responds with a successful response. When browsers see that the OPTIONS request is successful then the browser executes the actual request (GET, POST, DELETE, whatever).

Sometimes for local development you may need to overcome this as localhost will not be supported by the server. In this case you can use browser extensions that intercepts your xhr requests and mocks a successful OPTIONS request for your browser and your browser thinks server responded with successful for OPTIONS call so then it allows the call.

Sending the headers with your request will not work. The api server must allow options request to be returned with status 200 for your app to be able to make that call from browser.

All the above is based on that you sent the request from your browser the same way as from postman or curl. You can verify that if you use a network monitor app like Fiddler if you use windows. If you are on macOS or Linux, I am not aware of a tool like Fiddler, there must be tools but as I don't work on those platform, I cannot suggest another tool to monitor network.

Comment: it's NOT a CORS issue, as there are no CORS errors - do you know what the purpose of cors-anywhere.herokrap.com is? ... no, not even `probably` - you can edit the answer as many times as you like, as long as you think this has anything to do with a CORS error, your answer will be wrong

Comment: I am not aware of waht cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com does. Based on the OP I responded with I know as the OP doesn't provide enough information

Comment: Oh. Sorry. It's a well know way for beginners to bypass cors