# How to allow HTTP POST method with fetch api

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, http-status-code-405

I'm trying to make a post request to a local json file that i have running in my localhost server, however even when i specify all header parameters i still get status 405 method not allowed. I'm usin the live server extension in the vscode and i've already tried changing ports and the problem wasn't solved. I don't know if this is a problem with my local server or if my code is wrong.

```
        let book= new Book(title,author,year);

        let url = "../data/books.json";

        let init =
        {
            method:"POST",

            credentials:"include",

            mode:"cors",

            headers:
            {
                "Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*",

                "Content-type":"application/json",

                "Authorization":"*",

                "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",

                "Access-Control-Request-Method": "*",

                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*",

                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers":"Origin, Content-type, Accept, Authorization, Credentials"
            },

            body:JSON.stringify(book)
        }

        fetch(url,init)
            .then(function(res)
            {
                if(res.status == 200)
                    return res.json();
                else
                    throw new Error("Request Error");
            })
            .then(function(obj)
            {
                console.log(obj);
            })
            .catch(function(err)
            {
                alert(err.message);
            })
```

Comment: The error is not client-side, it's server-side. Your server doesn't want you to use the `POST` request. If you control the server, it might be a problem with your application code or server configuration.

Comment: Access-Control headers can't be set in request (well they can but are absolutely useless). They have to be set at endpoint in the response.

Comment: Also, `res.json()` returns a promise, so you'll need to either `await` it or use a `.then().catch()`.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37527962/add-cors-header-to-an-http-request-using-ajax for explanation of what you are doing wrong the CORS headers

Comment: note: the `method not allowed` issue may be due to the CORS preflight `OPTIONS` request sent by the browser, due to the nature of your request

Comment: @spafindoople OP is returning the `res.json()` promise just fine

Comment: i'm using a localhost generated by the live server extension from vscode, if the problem is the server not the code, what could i do to configure it to allow post requests?

Comment: Can you share you server-side code here ?

Comment: My bad, I thought they wanted to return the json content, not the promise.