# axios is giving response in 20 sec, but same api with same request payload is giving response in 6 sec from postman

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, fetch-api

i'm using axios for api calls from reactjs framework. 
by axios i'm getting response in 20sec, but when i make the same request from postman it is giving response in 6 secs.

i tried the same request by using fetch, it is also taking around 20 secs

```
     axios.post(URL, reqObject, {
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer '.concat(AccessToken)
            },
        }
        ).then(function (response) {

            console.log(" axios  APi call response ", response.data.value)

        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log("  error error");
            console.log(error);
        });
```

Comment: *"`'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'`"* makes no sense in a *client* request to a *server*. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37527962/add-cors-header-to-an-http-request-using-ajax At **best** it will be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like this is a cross-origin request to a slowly-responding server. Cross-origin POSTs require something called a "preflight" OPTIONS request on browsers. If the server is responding slowly, it may take a long time to respond to the OPTIONS request, and then a long time again to respond to the POST.

In contrast, since postman isn't a browser, it doesn't have to worry about CORS and can send the POST without sending the preflight OPTIONS, so only incurs the cost of the POST.

(If you're wondering why postman doesn't have to do the preflight but a browser does, I suggest reading through the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), [CORS on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), and the answers to the [question I linked in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37527962/add-cors-header-to-an-http-request-using-ajax).)

Comment: Hello sir, So what is the solution for this? I am also having same problem... postman respond in 0.5 seconds whereas my fetch request respond in 5seconds

Comment: @Ashh - The solution is to fix whatever it is that's making the server respond so slowly.

Comment: @Assh, I have same problem although I remove all the functions on backend and only left `res.json`, it takes about 1~2 secs.