# Request sent by axios ran by Laravel twice

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, axios

so i want to send request to Laravel from the frontend using axios, it's cross origin so the frontend is at `localhost:3000` and the backend at `localhost:8000/api`,

in the Laravel i already applied the CORS middleware with [this](https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors). in the axios i already set the headers.

axios setup

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = API_URL
axios.defaults.headers.common.Accept = 'application/json'
axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest'
axios.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
```

axios post and delete:

```
 function create(){
    return dispatch => {
        return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
            HTTP.get('/post/category/create')
                .then((data)=>{
                    return resolve(data.data.data)
                }).catch((data)=>{
                    return reject(data)
                })
        })
    }
}
export function destroy(data){
    return dispatch => {
        return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
            HTTP.delete(`/post/category/${data}`)
                .then((data)=>{
                    return resolve(data.data)
                }).catch((data)=>{
                    return reject(data)
                })
        })
    }
}
```

how i call the function :

```
 var SubmitCategory = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData(e.target)
        await setSubmit(true);
        await props.dispatch(insert(formData))
            .then(data=>{
                toaster(data.message,data.status)
                props.history.replace({
                    pathname: `/post/category`
                })
            })
            .catch(data=>{
                toaster(data.message,"error")
                setError(data)
            })
        await setSubmit(false)
    }


<form autoComplete="off" onSubmit={e=>SubmitCategory(e)}> <<--- onSubmit
...////
```

how the laravel function looks :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // return response()->json($request,500);
    try {
        DB::beginTransaction();
        $data = $request->all();

        $cat = Category::create($data);

        DB::commit();

        return response()->json([
            'status'     => 'success',
            'id'         => $cat->id,
            'code'       =>  200,
            'message'    => 'Category Created'
        ],200);

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        DB::rollback();
        return response()->json([
            'status'     => 'error',
            'code'       =>  500,
            'message'    => $e->getMessage()
        ],500);
    }
}
```

this happen to every method, so when i created something it would create two records, and when i deleted something the first will be successfully deleted while the second unwanted request fail (because it's already deleted).

my first thought was that axios sent two request with one of them being `OPTIONS` method, i did some google research that it cannot be turned of and some other ways to handle it, still nothing.

edit the cors.php file

```
<?php

    'paths' => ['api/*'],
    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
    'exposed_headers' => [],
    'max_age' => 600,
    'supports_credentials' => false,
```

Comment: facing the same issue, did u find any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're using CORS, the browser may need to send an `OPTIONS` request before the `GET` request. (If so, it does it automatically when you issue the `GET` with `XMLHttpRequest`/`fetch`/etc.) You need to distinguish between an `OPTIONS` request and a `GET` request on the server side and only actually do the work when you get the `GET`, not when you get the `OPTIONS` before it.

---

Side note: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a **response** header. You shouldn't tell `axios` to send it with a *request* (doing so doesn't do anything). [More on that here..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37527962/add-cors-header-to-an-http-request-using-ajax).

Comment: the `GET` method is fine, but it's the `POST` and `DELETE` method that being ran twice, i added the `cors.php` file if that helps.

so what do i need to change?

im sorry if my question seems weird it's my first time doing froentend and backend in different domain in using cors

Comment: @Asary - It's the same fundamental thing (and I'm glad you said it's `POST` and `DELETE`, it was a bit weird for `OPTIONS` to be done for a `GET` -- it is needed sometimes, but not usually). You need to tell Laravel to handle `OPTIONS`. (I don't use Laravel, so I don't know specifically how you do that.)

Comment: so i did that, i created a middleware so that any `OPTIONS` method return an empty 200 response,  i don't know if it's the best practice, but it works now, for the time being. thanks!

Comment: In the production environment, the `OPTIONS` method should be handled and terminated in your web server (Nginx for example) so that those requests do not reach the PHP engine.